# Crashing at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video

Tags: android, admob

I am using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads 17.0.0` and facing a lot of crashes since past few days, but I can't reproduce.

Stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException uriString

android.net.Uri$StringUri. (Uri.java:476)
android.net.Uri$StringUri. (Unknown Source)
android.net.Uri.parse (Uri.java:438)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video.a.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14366046@14.3.66 (040306-213742215):13)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video.gmsg.f.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14366046@14.3.66 (040306-213742215):148)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.j.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14366046@14.3.66 (040306-213742215):293)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.run (Unknown Source:4)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.dispatchMessage (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14366046@14.3.66 (040306-213742215):5)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:171)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6627)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:518)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Most affected versions:
Android 5.1, 6.0, 7.0 and 7.1.

Has anyone come across same error? Or any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in version `17.0.0` either you're using

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'    //or
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
```

You can check this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/JgVrHeRKcu4/XJAPHZ8RAQAJ) for more details.

According to [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/JgVrHeRKcu4/IaIK0IjtAgAJ) from Mobile Ads SDK Team member, issue has been fixed but there is no ETA as of now.

**EDIT**

I found that above issue is not related to particular admob version. From last week most of the apps with AdMob start crashing, It doesn't matter what admob version you're using. I think there is some issue with server side or how they delivered ads(may be getting null in response) and not handled in AdMob SDK level.

So Currently we've

- Issue with Server side
- May be some issue in version `17.0.0`

Issue already submitted to `Mobile Ads SDK` team so we've only option to wait for server side fixes or we may get another release after `17.0.0`.

---

Version `17.1.0` has been deployed on Google's Maven repository on `2018‑11‑07`

**EDIT 2**

Hopefully issue has been resolved from server side, response from most of developers that they are not getting above crash from last 24 hours.

**EDIT 3**

Issue has been [resolved](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/JgVrHeRKcu4/pmMJp8ptBQAJ) by Mobile Ads SDK Team.